# Modifying a 3d array using a 2D index with Numpy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array in three dimensions (a, b, c) and I need to modify the positions c indexed by an array in two dimensions (a, b).

I wrote a code that works as expected, but does anyone know if there is a way to solve this problem without the for loop?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randn(100, 5, 2)
mod = np.random.randn(100, 5)
ids = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=[100,5])
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(5):
        arr[i,j,ids[i,j]] = mod[i,j]
```

Comment: Hi. I don't understand how `ids = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=[100,5])` is helping you. It generates a 2D array filled randomly with 0s and 1s, which you then use to define which slice `mod[i, j]` gets assigned to. So in short when you assign `mod[i, j]`, on your last line, you are assigning it randomly to point `[i,j,0]` or `[i,j,1]` Are you doing this on purpose? If so, I don't understand what you are trying to do so my answer probably isn't what you are looking for. If this isn't a bug, could you please edit your answer to clarify your question? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your attention. That code is just a simplification of my problem. I defined arr, mod and ids as random to be able to run as an example. The short story is I am using an evolutionary algorithm in machine learning, and my code is taking much time to finish because the number of generations is so big. Then, I am trying to optimize it by eliminating loops. In this case, I need to change arr putting mod in the positions according to ids. If I get this, I will eliminate many loops in my code. I am reading the links in your answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to and set each *slice* of the array directly. I think this code shows the behaviour you are asking about:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]])
print(arr[:,:,2])
# Output: 
#[[ 3  6]
# [ 9 12]]

new2DSlice = np.array([[23, 26], [29, 32]])
arr[:,:,2] = new2DSlice
print(arr[:,:,2])
# Outupt:
#[[23 26]
# [29 32]]
```

`arr[:,:,2]` refers to the third slice of the array and, in this example, sets it directly.

You can read about NumPy's [array indexing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_indexing.asp) and [array slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp) on W3Schools.

Answer (score 1):

I got with this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randn(100, 5, 2)
mod = np.random.randn(100, 5)
ids = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=[100,5])
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(5)
arr[x[:,None],y,ids] = mod
```